# Не происходит установка зависимостей - Docker

Tags: docker, composer, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

 # Set public directory as root for Apache
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
    && php composer.phar install
```

При выполнении установки зависимостей composer выдает ошибку

> ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get
>   update    && apt-get install -y git   && curl --silent --show-error
>   https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   && php composer.phar install'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1

При этом если зайти напрямую в контейнер и выполнить установку через композер - то все работает.

Comment: замените на `FROM php:7.2-fpm`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ну мне какбы апач нужен.

Comment: у вас не устанавливается, так как `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html`. Вы можете это исправить если выполните `./composer.phar global require "laravel/installer"`, но для этого нужно опять уже устанавливать дополнительные компоненты.  Либо, легче будет, если FROM php:7.2-fpm будете использовать

Comment: нет никой разницы, что использовать, нужно лишь правильно выстроить процесс разработки и развертывания. FPM здесь не причем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сборка - `build: ...`, это про образ. А `volumes: ...` это про контейнер.

**В момент сборки директория не примонтирована и соответственно нет `composer.json`.**

Можно "бросать" файл composer.json в образ на этапе сборки (`COPY ...`), но при монтировании, в вашем случае, директория будет перекрываться локальной и в этом нет смысла. То есть нужно продумать, что и как монтировать.

Для разработки и для развертывания можно использовать разные подходы. Обычно, на этапе разработки, команды установки выполняются через `docker-compose run/exec ...`. А на этапе сборки образа файлы копируются и затем выполняются команды. Например:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y git   

...

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . /var/www/html

RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
  && php composer.phar install
```

> Конечно, можно кешировать/монтировать зависимости отдельно. Нужно посмотреть внимательно на проект и подумать как сделать удобней.